# full bleed detail for a responsive list

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a list of items that can expand to show further details(Category item 2 is expandable), 
I got to this point using two nested grids. which might not be the best solution

My problem is that I would want the detail's background to expand untill the sides of the layout similar to the header

from:

[image]

to:

[image]

One way to do this would be to add considerable margins to each side, and compensate with padding, but is there a more elegant way to achieve this layout?

```js
const detail = document.getElementById("detail")

function toggleDetails() {
  detail.classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    [full-start] minmax(1rem, 1fr) 
    [main-start] minmax(0, 40em) [main-end]
    minmax(1rem, 1fr) [full-end];
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  background: #eee;
}

.container > * {
  grid-column: main;
}

.header {
  grid-column: full;
  background: white;
}

.categories {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(9rem , 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.categories > li {
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}

#detail {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background: white;
}

#detail.visible {
  display: initial;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header container">
    <h1>John Doe</h1>
  </div>
  <div>Categories: </div>
  <ul class="categories">
    <li>Category 1</li>
    <li>Category 2
      <button onclick="toggleDetails()">+</button>
    </li>
    <li id="detail" class="visible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis illum earum, iusto repellendus repellat inventore possimus assumenda ipsa eum tempore nihil sed, eius facilis aliquam laboriosam placeat impedit atque ut.</li>
    <li>Category 3</li>
    <li>Category 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Without changing the whole layout i don't think you can. One other solution would be to use `before` and `after` pseudo-elements. But i wouldn't consider that solution 'elegant' either

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I applied such an aproach to the solution: https://codepen.io/dreiv/full/jpqeMB/

Comment: Yep. Something like that. Glad i could help.